# Remove the error "Download the capabilities failed : error downloading" while I connect a link through my WMS

Tags: wms, qgis-2, getcapabilities

I have installed QGIS Web Map Server on my PC and the GetCapabilities response looks like below in the screenshot:

[image: GetCapabilities response]

But when I import this link to QGIS for open my project file, I am getting an error which is shown below in the pic. I have my shapefile as "kgp.qgs" which do not have any attribute data. I made this file from Google Earth using "polygon" tool. Then I converted the .xml format to shapefile in QGIS which doesn't bring any attribute data with itself. I'm showing the image of my "kgp" shapefile without any attribute data.

[image]

[image]

Can you help me to solve out my problem ?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is less one of how to view your service in QGIS as one of how to configure a service.  Can you show the information in the GetCapabilities response for the Layers, so the first image shows the top part of the GetCapabilities response that you get when you make a request in a browser, this request is to see lower down in that response in the browser.  I think it will point to the actual error and therefore help you find a solution

Answer (score 3):

> But when i import this link to QGIS for open my project file

You don't use the full GetCapabilities request when specifying your WMS/WMST service.  You should use only the service end point, that is the part of the URL that specifies the service, to which a client (QGIS in this example) will add all the appropriate request parameters

So for example if your GetCapabilities request was:

http://wms.vsegei.ru/VSEGEI_Bedrock_geology2/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

In QGIS, when you define the service you would have:

http://wms.vsegei.ru/VSEGEI_Bedrock_geology2/wms?

In some services, where the map configuration file is referenced, you would include the map configuration parameter as well, like:

http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=path.to.map&

Comment: I use the link "http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=c:/OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin/kgp.qgs&" But still i'm getting the error. Any solution?

Comment: What if you use:  `http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=c:/OSGeo4W/apps/qg‌​is/bin/kgp.qgs&`.  Are you able to check what request is actually sent using say Fiddler, check my answer on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31076/why-might-my-mapserver-wms-layer-be-invisible-in-qgis-if-they-work-fine-in-a-bro/180637#180637 for details of how to do this

Comment: I tried in that way also but its giving the same error. One thing more, my shape file is "kgp.qgs" which has no attribute data. I made that file from Google earth by converting xml format to shp in qgis which don't bring any attribute data with itself.

Comment: Thanks i updated the question. I shown you error in my question by a pic which showing error " Failed to download capabilities". I am new user of QGIS and i don't know the meaning of the error. Can you solve out my problem?